# Ubuntu 22.04 Unable to run database via docker

Tags: mysql, docker, 22.04

Since I updated my Ubuntu version my Docker container mysql:8.0.23 is not able to successfully run anymore.

My Docker version is: 20.10.12
Docker Compose version is: v2.4.1

The problem itself is that if I start MySQL Version 8.0 or maria DB that I get an error something like this:

```
Data file './ibdata1' uses page size , but the innodb_page_size start-up parameter is 65536
```

or

```
./ib_logfile0 size is not a multiple of innodb_page_size
```

or

```
InnoDB: Invalid flags 0x4800 in ./ibdata1
```

So it seems that the problem with docker is somehow related to InnoDB.
What we tried out is changing the SQL configuration several times and removing all images but I still have those issues.

A colleague had the exact same issue and now moved back to the last ubuntu lts version.

Comment: This problem is related to an zfs issue described here: https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/13329

Comment: Same here. Ubuntu 22.04 in LXC Proxmox Container with `nesting` and `keyctl` features enabled. Mysql won't work.